# UITableView portion loses interaction after device rotation

Tags: ipad, uitableview, uiview, orientation, device-orientation

I have a UIViewController with a UIView subclass as a subview, and in here is a UITableView added as a subview of that UIView, as follows:

```
UIViewController
-UIView
--UITableView (plucked from a UITableViewController)
```

On an iPad, if I load the view controller in either orientation I can interact with the table view perfectly. However, if I rotate the device to a new orientation - I have code that alters the frames to make it fit the new resolution, but a small area of the table does not respond to touches and whatnot.

eg, we rotate portrait to landscape: if you imagine a portrait shape placed over a landscape screen - this area remains responsive, but a small strip to the right hand side does not respond.

Does anyone have any ideas what I may have missed? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I have successfully verified the CGRect frames of all objects from the tableview cells through to the top UIViewController.

Comment: Do you online resize the UITableView but not the parent UIView maybe?

Comment: I have successfully NSLogged all frame bounds of the tableview in question through to the top UIViewController, and they match up. The table view is pulled from a UIViewController originally but this other VC is released - might the tableview still be looking for it's original owner?

Comment: Hmmm... not entirely impossible. Why would you rip it from one VC to add it to another anyway? Doesn't sound like the most elegant solution :)

Comment: Of course you are absolutely correct - I'm tinkering with some files from cocoacontrols for an RSS reader for a universal app - it works great apart from this orientation issue on the iPad.

Answer (score 0):

The area that looses its interaction must have fallen outside its superview's frame after rotation.

you can check that by setting tableView.clipSubviews = YES;

using this, will crop the tableview portion falling outside the superview.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the only available property is tableView.clipsToBounds, which unfortunately hasn't done anything when placed in all super views.